# When using a base URL in a controller my static resources are no longer available

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a basic spring boot app that I am creating and I have an admin controller with that will give me a URL of /admin/**. My problem is that this URL then changes how I access static resources by prefixing the URL with /admin instead of just using /**.

How do I make it so that my static resources can still be accessed from the /admin/** URL as they are from the /** URL?

Example request that returns an error:
GET http://localhost:8080/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css

Above request does work with this request: 
GET http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.min.css

But I don't know a good, dynamic solution to remove the prefix in Thymeleaf or Spring. Really don't want to have to add something different to every HTML page.

How I am accessing my resources on HTML pages:

```
    <link href="../../static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      th:href="@{css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

How I am prefixing the URL in my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

@Autowired
ModelAndViewService modelAndViewService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/developer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String developer(Model model, Authentication authentication) {
    modelAndViewService.developerList(model,authentication);
    return "admin/developerList";
}
```

}

I added this to my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to attempt to fix the problem:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**","/admin/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Hoping it's an easy fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the Thymeleaf href.

```
    <link href="../../static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  th:href="@{css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

There are a few changes to make to this:

- Don't need the second href, only need the th:href.
- The th:href needs to be changed to the 'server relative' version which is done prepending ~ to the th:href link.

My code now reads as such:

```
    <link th:href="@{~/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I have changed this all over the application and it works for all different URLs. The prepended ~ will make your resources dynamically load to any page you return from the server no matter what the request URL is.

More on this here: [Thymeleaf URL syntax document](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)